# How can I use .filter() on an array to remove only 'NaN' but not strings and numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, nan

I tried using `isNaN(value)` and `!isNaN(value)` but I am unable to remove the NaN element in the give code without removing the strings. (Obviously because string is not a number).

```
function cleaner(arr) {
  return = arr.filter(function f(value) {return (value !== false && value !== null && value !== 0 && value !== undefined)});
}
cleaner([7, "eight", false, null, 0, undefined, NaN, 9, ""]);
```

The above code should return `[7, "eight", 9, ""];`

Comment: P.s, I think I could have worded the title better but I'm not sure how.

Comment: `false` and `null` and `undefined` are not `NaN`s. Only `NaN` is `NaN`

Comment: `NaN` stands for `Not A Number`.

Comment: @choz `NaN` comes from the IEEE754 standard. It **does not** mean "anything that is not a number".

Comment: `.filter(x => !Number.isNaN(x))` in ES6

Comment: Regardless, the last line of my post will explain what I actually want, to quell any confusion.

Comment: Guys, seriously, the question has nothing to do with `NaN`s.

Comment: Just check if `typeof` of the `value` is either a `string` or a `number` and you're done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will return only numbers (without 0) and strings (including empty ones).

```js
function cleaner(arr) {
   return arr.filter(function(item){ 
      return typeof item == "string" || (typeof item == "number" && item);
              /** Any string**/        /** Numbers without NaN & 0 **/
   });
}
console.log(cleaner([7, "eight", false, null, 0, undefined, NaN, 9, ""]));
//[7, "eight", 9, ""]
```

Using ES2015 [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) syntax

```
array.filter(item => typeof item == "string" || (typeof item == "number" && item));
```

```js
var filteredArr = [7, "eight", false, null, 0, undefined, NaN, 9, ""].filter(item => typeof item == "string" || (typeof item == "number" && !isNaN(item) && item));

console.log(filteredArr);
```

Comment: close, but it still does not remove the 0.

Comment: @salmanxk now without 0, I thought you said numbers and string, but I removed 0 now.

Comment: Well, in case it matters, this will nuke all functions, objects, arrays. Is that what you want, or you don't care?

Answer (score 3):

Some ways to detect whether `x` is `NaN`:

- `Number.isNaN(x)` (ES6)
- `Object.is(x, NaN)` (ES6)
- `x !== x`
- `(typeof x === 'number') && isNaN(x)`

**Note**: `isNaN` alone is not a reliable way to check if a value is `NaN`!

Comment: Oh gosh, you answered the title without checking the question body?

Comment: @zerkms No, I read it. OP is using `filter` to remove some items from an array. He wants to remove `NaN`s too, but using `!isNaN` removed both `NaN` and strings. That's because `isNaN` is not a reliable way to check if a value is `NaN`. Or that's what I understood, at least.

Comment: @zerkms It's **you** who didn't read the question! XD "*I tried using `isNaN(value)` and `!isNaN(value)` but I am unable to remove the `NaN` element in the give code without removing the strings*".

Comment: Lol, I've got caught

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to filter out all falsy values **except** empty strings, all you need is

```
function cleaner(arr) {
  return arr.filter(function(value) {
    return value === '' || value;
  });
}
```

If you had wanted to filter out all falsy values **including** empty strings, you could have done:

```
function cleaner(arr) {
  return arr.filter(Boolean);
}
```

Comment: Btw, that's not what OP wanted.

Comment: running your code(`filter(function(value) { return isNaN(value); }`)
) on the array `[7, "eight", NaN,]` returns `["eight", null]`. I need it to return  `[7,"eight]`.

Comment: There is a reason I did not use `.filter(Boolean)`; `Boolean` returns false on all 0, -0, null, false, NaN, undefined, and the empty string (""). I need it to return on some of these but not all.

Comment: No, actually you want to return false on **all but one (`""`)**. That's why it makes sense to simply list that single exception, as I have done in the answer above. The accepted answer has the unfortunate behavior that it removes all objects, arrays, functions, regexps, etc. etc., which may or may be what you want, but seems like a bug waiting to happen. Also it's long and ugly.

Comment: Hey @MarcosCasagrande, please re-read the question. Him saying he "wanted numbers and strings" is a pure fantasy made up by you. The sample code he gave would in fact **preserve** functions etc., so it's a perfectly reasonable assumption that he would want to, and a purely arbitrary assumption by you that he would not.